# how to Parsing multiple level JSON using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this code example below working just fine with one level json file, not able to parse the data from multi level jason file.

so i'm trying to make this code work with the json file located on the link below, any help will be appreciated.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahammoudi/jason_data/master/jsoncountry2.json

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</h2><br /><br />
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('country');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahammoudi/jason_data/master/json_country.json', function(data){

   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if(id == 'country')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
  var country_id = $(this).val();
  if(country_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('state', country_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
   $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
  var state_id = $(this).val();
  if(state_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('city', state_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "Not able to parse" is a bit vague. Can you set it up as a jsfiddle?

Comment: the problem is,  i dont know to to parse multi level json. as the one in the link. as you can see the code parse first level (id) but not sure how to parse (all_ids.country_id.parent.parent_id) specially i'll be dealing with these two levels at the same time.

Comment: Well you address deeper nodes with dot formation. Say I have:
```
things: {ball: 'yellow', truck: 'red', house: { rooms: 5, color: orange }}
```

I address the color of the house via things.house.color.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: you taling about two levels, the two levels works just fine, the issue i'm facing is 4 levels, anything over two levels will error out as undefined. and i don not control json file, i'm calling it to get the data, so there is no way to change it.